# Is it possible to get mods onto Medieval II: Total War demo

Tags: mods, medieval-2-total-war

I have recently got the demo of Medieval II on Steam and would like to know if I can apply the Third Age: Total War mod. If I can't do it with the demo then, how I can do it when I get the full game.

Comment: You'll almost certainly need the full game.

Comment: The bold doesn't really help your question, so I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 2):

**FOR THIS TO WORK, YOU ALSO NEED THE 'KINGDOMS' EXPANSION PACK**

The best place to get the mod is [HERE](https://www.moddb.com/mods/third-age-total-war). There are 3 separate files to download. Once they have downloaded, run each individually and save it to your Total War Medieval 2 folder

eg: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\Common\Medieval 2 Total War

Once there, you should have a third age folder. The easiest way to get it to run is to then rename the folder to one of the other DLC campaigns (I used teutonic as I don;t play it often), then cut/paste the actual teutonic folder elsewhere on your computer where you can retrieve it later should you want to.

Then you simply load up the game through steam, and load up the Teutonic campaign and Third Age will start.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need the full game; I've tried it myself.

As for how to do it in the full game, I do not know.